# Select amount from one table by

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to select amount by `CustomerID`, `Category`, `Store` and `City`.

Please correct this query if you can?

```
var query = db.Amounts.Where(x => x.CustomerID == Convert.ToInt32(lkpCustomer.EditValue) &&
                  x.CatagoryID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_Catagory.EditValue) && x.StoresID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_from.EditValue) &&
                  x.CityID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_to.EditValue)).Select(x => x.Amount1).ToList();
RateSpinEdit.EditValue = query;
```

description:

[image]

Comment: The editor has a code formatting option which will make your code readable.

Comment: You could make 3 queries - one per Categrory, 1 per Cusomer, 1 per store and 1 per city. Trying to compress it by any more, is just going to cause issues and not provide any usefull data.

Comment: Do you get any compiler errors?  The query looks good, but without the Table definitions I can't tell if you will get compiler errors, runtime exceptions, or just no data.  What did you use to get the picture you posted?  Is the picture the results in c# without the WHERE filtering?  Your query is only returning one value (x.Amount1)  I think you want to modify the Select as follows : .Select(x => new {id = x.ID, category = x.CatagoryID, store = x.StoresID}).ToList();

Comment: If you're wanting to apply the result to a SpinEdit control then instead of `db.Amounts.Where(...).Select(x=>x.Amount).ToList()` try `db.Amounts.Where(...).Select(x=>x.Amount).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Hello! Your query needs to have more details. Would you be able to elicit your requirement in further detail?

Comment: Hello Dears:thank you all ,I have one form and this table contain 4 lookupEdite and one spinEdite  I need to fillspin edited with amount value after choose customer ,category,store and city

Comment: i had try this but not working ,using (var db = new dbDataContext())
            {
                  RateSpinEdit.EditValue = db.Amounts.Where(x => x.CustomerID == Convert.ToInt32(lkpCustomer.EditValue) &&
                x.CatagoryID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_Catagory) &&
                 x.StoresID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_from.EditValue) &&
                x.CityID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_to.EditValue)).Select(y => y.Amount1).First(); 

            }

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to group the value of the `amount` column according to below fields :

`CustomerID`, `Category`, `Store`, and `City`.

In this condition, the below code maybe be the answer to your question :

```
var query = (from p in Amounts
         group p by new { p.CustomerID, p.CatagoryID, p.StoresID, p.CityID}
         into grp
         where 
         (
            p => p.CustomerID    == Convert.ToInt32(lkpCustomer.EditValue) &&
                 p.CatagoryID    == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_Catagory.EditValue) &&
                 p.StoresID      == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_from.EditValue) &&
                 p.CityID        == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_to.EditValue)            
         )
         select new 
         {
                grp.key.ID,
                grp.key.CategoryID,
                grp.key.CustomerID,
                grp.key.StoresID,
                grp.key.CityID,
                SumOfAmount = grp.Sum(p => p.Amounts)            
         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help  . I use this code and it works success:

using (var db = new dbDataContext())
            { var datasource =db.amounts;

```
            var query = from amount in datasource
                        where amount.CatagoryID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_Catagory.EditValue)&&
                        amount.CustomerID == Convert.ToInt32(lkpCustomer.EditValue)&&
                        amount.StoresID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_from.EditValue)&&
                        amount.CityID == Convert.ToInt32(lkp_to.EditValue)
                        select amount;
            RateSpinEdit.EditValue = query.Select(x => x.Amount1).FirstOrDefault();
```